# Text editor with font colouring

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

Does Ubuntu have a text editor with choosing the colours of font? I don't mean those which highlight programming language syntax with colours for different types of statements. I just mean regular text editors (not office programs).

Or do any offer extensions which allow the same thing?

Comment: Text editor that can save text color will save it not as text but a kind of special format. Why not use LO Writer and not invent anything else?

Comment: This might have your answer: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480564#post_9297954

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the font color, you can use a terminal based text editor and you can set the font color of your terminal.

nano, vi, and vim are just a few you can use.